# Replacing entire tree item in Redux with different reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Given the following redux state tree:

```
{
    app: {...},
    config: {...},
    page_data: {...}
}
```

How would I replace the contents of `page_data` with an entire separate reducer depending on the page a user is on?

For example I could have three reducers `user`, `products`, `competitions`. If I switched from a user page to a product page I'd want the `page_data` branch to show:

```
{
   page_data: {
       productPage: {...}
   }
}
```

with no reference to `user` as I don't want to bloat the app state and also don't need that data on the product page.

*Note: I'm using combineReducers for reference.*

Is this possible and what is the best approach?

Comment: On the product page, `dispatch` an action containing the `productPage` and create the new state with `productPage` in the `reducer`.

Comment: Would that still include the userPage in the app state though?

Comment: No. You can create a totally new state like this:  `Object.assign({ },  oldState, { page_data: { productPage: {... } } } )`

Answer (score 0):

Using same name for multiple reducers is definitely wrong. Not just it isn't supported, it's wrong practice. You can achieve this using `FLUSH_PAGE_DATA` action. Dispatching this action will flush the page data in all the reducers. It'll Look something like this.

```
case 'FLUSH_PAGE_DATA':
    return {  };
```

Then based on you active page, which you'll pass in every action, you can create different structure of page data.